# How to be bad at Wordle

Tags: strategy, wordle

There are many sites that help with solving [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html), including some that use [Information Theory to find an optimal solution](https://jonathanolson.net/experiments/optimal-wordle-solutions) There is also a New York Times app called [Wordle Bot](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/upshot/wordle-bot.html) (behind their paywall unfortunately) that scores your solution on SKILL (Did you minimize the expected number of turns it would take to solve the puzzle?) and LUCK (Did your guesses eliminate more solutions than expected?).

I'd like to do something different. I'd like to find a strategy that minimizes LUCK, i.e. I'd like to do worse than my friend (we compete on doing the puzzle) by taking more turns to guess the answer, but in a clever way that doesn't affect my SKILL score too much. I can start from a position of knowing the true answer by solving it elsewhere (or looking it up on one of the "cheat" sites) but I'd like to make many good but wrong guesses before putting in the right answer.

My objective is to "prove" to my friend that the reason she always does better than me is just pure luck ;-). No, really it's because I thought it's an interesting puzzle problem.

What's the best strategy to minimize LUCK?

Comment: "What's the best strategy to minimize LUCK?" [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Comment: In case you don't already know about it, I'd suggest you try [Absurdle @ Things Of Interest](https://qntm.org/files/absurdle/absurdle.html).  The only "luck" in this version of the game is *bad* luck.

Comment: @bobble it is inconsistent to flag this as open-ended and not other open-ended puzzles. If we really were strict about open-endedness, then even cool puzzles like florian's new one (and most riddles) must be flagged too. Just my opinion.

Comment: There are many different ways to win wordle consistently without luck but skill- Flame, shunt,brick,podgy and stead,flung,chirp,womby and examples of 4 words that give you 20 letters, effective allowing you to guess the word in the last two guesses.

Comment: @JLee in this case we're being asked to optimize something that most people don't have access to: a paywalled algorithm which isn't described. There's no way to prove a best answer. For riddles, there is a way to have a best answer: what fits the clues best, which for a well-designed puzzle is obvious. Furthermore, we're never going to have perfect consistency, especially now that I have a summer job and can't watch the site as much :)

Comment: @bobble. hahaha by the way thanks for all your site-watching.

Comment: Would we be assuming that this is on Hard mode or not?

Comment: I don't know what the NYT's bot does. But if I'm correctly understanding the description and correctly guessing what it might mean, it seems like there isn't actually anything you can do to maximize or minimize LUCK, at least "to first order". Isn't the idea that for each word you play, it looks at the distribution of what-that-specific-word-would-have-eliminated, _given the information you had when you played it_, and compares it with what the actual result it gave you turns out to eliminate? And doesn't that mean that [...continues]

Comment: ... whatever word you play, the expected value of LUCK is zero? (Or the median value. Or something broadly along those lines, depending on exactly what the bot is doing.) And doesn't that mean that _by definition_ you can't influence its value much by your choices? Maybe you can somehow pick word A so that when you then pick word B, the distribution of eliminations it gives you is more likely to have a certain shape, or something, and that might e.g. make you usually get lower LUCK at the "cost" of occasionally getting much higher LUCK so that it averages out OK, [...continues]

Comment: ... but surely none of that is going to do anything like e.g. making sure that your LUCK value is going to be small.

Comment: An interesting example came up the other day. I had got to line 3 and my choices had left three remaining possibilities. "bloat", "float" and "gloat". Entering them in that order gave me a 20% luck score as the true answer was "gloat". The problem is how best to engineer situations like that.